# Arduino⇔Python間のシリアル通信で，ボーレート(bps)によって謎のデータが先頭に混入するのはなぜでしょうか

Tags: python3, arduino, シリアル通信

使用機器：Arduio Uno

以下のようなコードでArduino⇔PC間をUSBで接続して通信しています．
PCから文字列"123"をバイトに変換し，Arduinoに送信．Arduinoはデータをそのまま返信し，PC側で受信，という流れです．
Arduino側：

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
  byte data = Serial.read();
  Serial.write(data);
  }
}
```

Python(PC)側：

```
import serial, time


print("Open Port")
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "COM3"     #デバイスマネージャでArduinoのポート確認
ser.baudrate = 115200 #Arduinoと合わせる
ser.setDTR(False)     #DTRを常にLOWにしReset阻止
ser.open()            #COMポートを開く

# 送信
sendStr = "123"
sendData = sendStr.encode()
ser.write(sendData)

# 受信
while True:
    str = ser.read()
    print(str)
    int_data = int.from_bytes(str, 'big')
    print(int_data)


ser.close()           #COMポートを閉じる
```

このとき，ボーレート(bps)を9600や14400，57600としたときは，正常にb'1'，b'2'，b'3'と受信できるのですが，ボーレートを300や19200，115200とすると先頭にb'\xff'やb'x0c'といったデータが混入します．
なぜでしょうか？

以下，各ボーレートでの実行結果です．

```
300    : b'\x0c' b'\x8c' b'1' b'2' b'3'
1200,2400,4800,9600,14400 : 正常受信
19200  : b'\xff' b'1' b'2' b'3'
28800  : b'\xff' b'1' b'2' b'3'
38400  : b'\xfe' b'1' b'2' b'3'
57600  : 正常受信
115200 : b'xf0' b'xf0' b'1' b'2' b'3'
```

Answer (score 1):

提示コードだと典型的「無手順通信」です。つまり電文がどこから始まってどこから終わるのか受け取る側 = Arduino にとって不明です。そのためたまたま電文の途中から受け取る可能性があって、そうすると化けて見えます。ボーレートによって化けたり化けなかったりはたまたまですね（もっと詳しい「化け原理」の解説が必要ですか？）

なので手順（開始＋終了の約束）を決めてください。これをプロトコルと言います。

- `STX` + 本文 + `ETX` でもいいし
- 本文 + 改行 でもいいし
- 本文 + 無信号時間　でもいいし
- あなた独自の手順でもよいです（開始終了が確実にわかればヨシ）

最初のやつなら受け取る側は

- 受信データが `STX` 以外の値なら全部無視する
- `STX` が来たら `ETX` までを受け取る (送る側がバグっている可能性を鑑みて、バッファオーバーフローにならないよう注意）
- `ETX` が来たら初期状態に戻る

最初の１回は捨てられちゃいますがしかたないです。

送受信データの妥当性を保証するために「チェックサム」とか「 CRC 」とかでチェックコードを付けるともっと良いですね。